# Order list in jquery with persistence using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-2.0

i know how to make a list order and provide shorting using drag and drop in jquery but i dont how to provide persistence using ajax with it.

i me as i drag-drop items in list for ordering their order should me saved in database.

i found such examples in PHP but not able to find it in asp.net

http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/dynamic_drag_drop_with_jquery_and_php.php

please provide me solution that how to implement it in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution at:

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/11/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and.html

please provide me more if you have any good one.. thanks